# convert structure to char pointer in c#

Tags: c#, c++, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

Below is the piece of code written in c++, how can i convert it in c#. If you check the pams_get_msgw function , the first param is of (char*), how can i pass the same in c# .

```
                struct 
                {
                    short m_nStatus;
                    short m_nReg_Id;
                    short m_nNumber_Reg;
                } oRegReply;

                short nBufSize = sizeof(oRegReply);
                q_address   oSenderQueue;
                nMsgType = MSG_TYPE_SBS_REG_REPLY;
                cPriority = 0;
                lTimeout = 300; // 30 seconds

                //Wait for reply telegram from SBS server
                lStatus = pams_get_msgw((char *) &oRegReply, &cPriority, &oSenderQueue,
                                        &nMsgClass, &nMsgType, &nBufSize, &nMsgLen,
                                        &lTimeout, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
                                        NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

My c# declaration for **pams_get_msgw** function is like this

```
  [DllImport("DmqCl32.dll")]
  public static extern int pams_get_msgw(StringBuilder msg_area, string priority, out q_address source,
                                               out short clas, out short type,
                                               ref short msg_area_len, out short len_data, ref int timeout,
                                               ref int sel_filter, out PSB psb, out ShowBuffer show_buffer,
                                               ref int show_buffer_len, ref int large_area_len, out int large_size,
                                               [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string nullarg_3);
```

and actual c++ declaration

```
typedef long (CALLBACK* PAMSGETMSGW)(char *,char *,q_address *, short *, short *, short *,
                                     short *, long *, long *, struct PSB *,  
                                     struct show_buffer *, long *, char *, char *, char * );
```

How can i pass structure into first argument, the way doing in c++ 
?

Comment: you'd probably pass a `string`, and you'd also probably have to change your `struct` into a `class` and give it a proper `ToString()` method, depending on your requirements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to declare your struct in C# as a *class* rather than a struct, and then you can just pass it via P/Invoke without using the `ref` keyword.

What's happening is that the C code is so ancient that it's using a `char*` where it should be using a `byte*`.

Anyway, the default marshaling for P/Invoke handles pinning and passing object references for most cases, so it will likely work if you just pass a class object. (Many C++ structs can be declared as classes at the C# side which can make the P/Invoke easier.)

You don't show the C declaration for `pams_get_msgw()` but it looks like you must also use `Marshal.Sizeof(RegReply)` for the value of `msg_area_len` (where `RegReply` is your C# class for C's `oRegReply` struct).

BTW: Do you need assistance with declaring the C# version of the `oRegReply` struct?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, here is the declaration of function in c++,   typedef long (CALLBACK* PAMSGETMSGW)(char *,char *,q_address *, short *, short *, short *,
          short *, long *, long *, struct PSB *,  
          struct show_buffer *, long *, char *, char *, char * );

Comment: Yes, so it looks like the 6th parameter (`msg_area_len`) must be set to `Marshal.Sizeof(RegReply)` - I have no idea why it is a pointer tho. But you'll have to pass it as a `ref short` as you already are.